# Fitering records upto specified value in a column based on id R

Tags: r

I have the following data(df)

```
    Id     event    label
     1    eating    0
     1    walking   0
     1    sleeping  finish
     1    dreaming  stage changed
     1    snoring   0
     2    drinking  0
     2    running   finish
     2    resting   0
     2    relaxing  0
```

Here for every Id(case), label = "finish" indicates the completion of case,
I'm trying to consider cases till the label = "finish" and remove the remaining records for that Id. which may look like,

```
    Id     event    label
     1    eating    0
     1    walking   0
     1    sleeping  finish
     2    drinking  0
     2    running   finish
```

I tried following way but it doesn't help. any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 df <- data.table(df)
 setDT(df)[label =="finish", by=parent_id]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` we could do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:which(label == "finish")], by = Id]
#   Id    event  label
#1:  1   eating      0
#2:  1  walking      0
#3:  1 sleeping finish
#4:  2 drinking      0
#5:  2  running finish
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If every ID has a "finish" and the obs are all ordered as above, a longer answer using base R would be

```
start <- which(!duplicated(df$ID))
end <- which(df$label =="finish")
keepObs <- unlist(lapply(unique(df$ID), function(i) start[i]:end[i]))

dfKeepers <- df[keepObs,]
```

Comment: Thanks for using base R.

Comment: @Rodrigo sure thing. I work in an environment where it can be difficult to get new packages installed, so tend to prefer base R solutions when they make sense.

Comment: Not only for that. It's a good practice to avoid external libraries whenever possible.